# Relocating controls in UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uilabel, frame, move

I have a problem trying to relocate a UILabel when loading a View. I can move the label if I run this code

```
lTarget.frame = CGRectOffset(lTarget.frame, 0.0f, -75.0f);
```

from for example a button action, it works properly. But where should I put this code if I want it to be called on the view load?, I tried viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but this doesn't work.

I need to relocate this label because I want a different layout for the 3.5 inch screen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a xib or storyboard with Autolayout enabled, it will cause your view size and position to be recalculated between the calls to `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

You should be able to move your code to `viewDidAppear:` or turn off Autolayout.